# Show react-select option values in DOM (to be captured by Selenium)

Tags: reactjs, selenium, react-select

We have React-based frontend and use [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) to implement all dropdown menus. We also have Selenium-based automation testing in place from the past. Using Selenium, we're able to get display text (label) of all the options from each dropdown (after expanding it), but we're looking for a way to also get **values** of all the options.

Let's use the example from [react-select Getting Started page](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} />
)
```

In page DOM, after clicking to expand the dropdown, we would get something like this:

```
<div class=" css-2b097c-container">
  ...
  <div class=" css-1pahdxg-control">
    <div class=" css-g1d714-ValueContainer">
      <div class=" css-1wa3eu0-placeholder">Select...</div>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class=" css-26l3qy-menu">
    <div class=" css-4ljt47-MenuList">
      <div class=" css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-3-option-0" tabindex="-1">Chocolate</div>
      <div class=" css-1n7v3ny-option" id="react-select-3-option-1" tabindex="-1">Strawberry</div>
      <div class=" css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-3-option-2" tabindex="-1">Vanilla</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we see the display text of currently selected item (which is "Select...", i.e. nothing) and `<div>` for each item from the dropdown menu (carrying its display text), but values are not present for any item.

**Question:**
Is there a way (maybe some component property we missed) to make react-select also add item **values** to page DOM (e.g. is some additional `<div>`, so we could capture it with Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `Option` component and add your own data attribute which can contain anything you want. In the example below, I'll pass the `value` of each option to the `data-value` attribute, so it can be displayed in the DOM:

```js
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const Option = (props) => {
  const optionProps = {
    ...props,
    innerProps: {
      ...props.innerProps,
      "data-value": props.data.value
    }
  };
  return <components.Option {...optionProps} />;
};

export default () => (
  <Select options={colourOptions} components={{ Option }} />
);
```

#### Result

When you pass this list of options to the `Select` component

```
export const colourOptions = [
  { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
  { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#FF5630', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
  { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' },
  { value: 'green', label: 'Green', color: '#36B37E' },
  { value: 'forest', label: 'Forest', color: '#00875A' },
  { value: 'slate', label: 'Slate', color: '#253858' },
  { value: 'silver', label: 'Silver', color: '#666666' },
];
```

The DOM nodes will look like this:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67126165/show-react-select-option-values-in-dom-to-be-captured-by-selenium]

Comment: Thank you very much! We'll retest and update this comment with the results!